# Restricting Attribute usages only for Public and Protected Variables c#

Tags: c#, attributes

Is it possible to restrict an attribute usage to just protected and public variables. I just want to restrict to private variables.

Comment: As Mehrdad explained, you can't do that. Could you tell us why you want to restrict attributes in such a way? Could you tell us your usecase?

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't do that. You can restrict attribute usage only based on the type of the target, not anything else.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MethodOnlyAttribute : Attribute { 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), here's an example of a field which can only be applied to a public or protected field:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class MyAttribute : OnFieldAccessAspect
{
    public override bool CompileTimeValidate(System.Reflection.FieldInfo field)
    {
        if (field.IsPublic || field.IsFamily)
        {
            throw new Exception("Attribute can only be applied to Public or Protected fields");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot.  The [AttributeTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx) enumeration lists which application elements you can constrain attribute usage to.